# Is it bad that I'm tempted to structure a lot of my jQuery code as plugins?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Since I learned how to write my own plugins in jQuery, I find I'm tempted to approach my javascript that way any time I'm building a page with any complexity to it.  Obviously it's silly when we're talking about 10 lines of code, but when I'm going to be building a page with a couple hundred lines of javascript (or more), it seems the easiest way to:

- Pass data (or even just options) from my PHP script into javascript -- `$("#myform").myPagePlugin({options}, {data});`
- Gives me a "master" object in the DOM to attach my data to, instead of something hacky like global variables
- Make my code re-usable later
- "Plug in" my javascript to the page in a familiar way

Am I digging myself into a hole if I start doing this?  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My only critique would be that you're creating a jQuery plugin it seems you are never really planning on using again. This adds the overhead of running the JavaScript that jQuery runs to initialize a plugin when that overhead is not worth it, since the module will never be used again.

Instead of a jQuery plugin, why don't you create a JavaScipt object which is namespaced? For example:

```
var mypage = {};
mypage.controller = function(){

} //your preferred JavaScript object notation here.
```

Or is this namespaced approach what you are refering to as "hacky"?  If so, I would respectfully disagree.

Comment: Interesting.  So just make an empty object, and then attach everything to it?  I definitely don't think that's hacky.

Comment: yup, using hashes in JS is incredibly convenient.

Comment: A little follow-up. I found a great article on the "Module pattern" for javascript.  Looks very useful: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.  Similar result as the above method, but it also adds in the ability to handle private/public properties.

Comment: Hey Keith, this is definitely one of the nice oo patterns in JavaScript.  For discussion by the guy who many consider to be THE expert, get "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglass Crockford.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with hashes *per* Zalavsky is that while a hash creates a namespace quite gracefully, it does not create a scope.  Often you need module-wide static variables that are **not** available to the outside world.  In those case, I would write

```
var mypage = function() {
  var some_module_static ; 
  return {
    controller :function(){
       // use some_module_static here
    }
  };
}();
```

Whenever you don't need a separate scope, yeah, use the hash.

Write a plug-in whenever you are writing a module that is conceptually useful beyond whatever you are doing at the moment.